# Updating current row when clicked upon in TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

So I have code that works if the user selects a different row than the one currently selected

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue == null) {
                    updateDetails(oldValue);
                    return;
                }
                updateDetails(newValue);
            });
}
```

However, I want this to work if the user clicks on the same value as well - basically, there's a part of the code that modifies an image shown but that image doesn't update itself unless I click on another row then go back to the row I was previously on. I would like to be able to update the row I'm on simply by clicking on it (which would call updateDetails) but can't seem to figure this out...

Comment: Simply checking the `observable` doesn't work? (Haven't tried this yet, so I better ask...)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `rowFactory` and add a mouse listener to it.

#### Example

This displays the old value property of the last item clicked and the new item clicked as text of the `Label`.

```
TableView<Item> tv = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Item("foo"), new Item("bar"), new Item("42")));

Label label = new Label();

TableColumn<Item, String> valueColumn = new TableColumn<>("value");
valueColumn.setCellValueFactory(d -> d.getValue().valueProperty());
tv.getColumns().add(valueColumn);

EventHandler<MouseEvent> eventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    private Item lastItem;

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            TableRow<Item> source = (TableRow<Item>) event.getSource();
            if (!source.isEmpty()) {
                label.setText(MessageFormat.format("old: {0}; new: {1}", lastItem == null ? null : lastItem.getValue(), (lastItem = source.getItem()).getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
};

tv.setRowFactory(t -> {
    TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(eventHandler);

    return row;
});
```

```
public class Item {

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    private final StringProperty value = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public void setValue(String val) {
        value.set(val);
    }

    public StringProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }

}
```